# Machine Learning: Using a model that overfits but performs well in CV

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, knn, overfitting-underfitting

I am currently training a KNeighborsClassifier model on sports betting data where the outcomes are normally 50/50.

My current training dataset overfits when trained, but has a mean precision score of 0.54 when training using cross validation.

What next steps can I take to ensure the model does not overfit? To note, I am using the whole training dataset and only 3 features.

```
params = {
             'leaf_size': [10,15,20],
             'n_jobs':[1,2,3],
             'n_neighbors':[10,20,30],
}

gs_knn = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
                   param_distributions=params,
                      scoring='precision', cv=10, n_iter=100,
                   random_state=0)
gs_knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
gs_knn.best_estimator_
```

Comment: It could very well be that the 0.54 score you are getting is not statistically different from the 0.5 you would get with random guessing. In this case the overfitting would be evident.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do other than picking a simpler model or reducing features???

Comment: Improve the features is the best thing to do. The question does not give enough information to help you more.

Comment: Try different values for k, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by another user, adjusting your values for k should improve your model.

You can perform a gridsearch to find the best k value using something like the below:

```
#select your range

    k_range = list(range(1, 31))
    param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=k_range)

#define your gridsearch 

    grid = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

#fit it to your data

    grid.fit(X, y)

#see your best k

    grid.best_params_
```

Comment: Thanks.
I have added the code above to my answer. One more quick question:

I want to add a pipeline in with a StandardScaler(), how would I go about this 

`model_pipe = Pipeline([ ('std_scal', StandardScaler()), ('model', KNeighborsClassifier())])`

When I add this code as the estimator into the GridSearchCV, I get an error message. Any advice?